# Complex analysis, residues

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, residue-calculus

> Find the residue at $z=0$ of $f(z)=\dfrac{\sinh z}{z^4(1-z^2)}$.

I did 
\begin{align}
\frac{\sinh z}{z^4(1-z^2)} & =\frac{1}{z^4}\left[\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!)}\right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{2n}\right)\right] \\[8pt]
& =\frac{1}{z^4}\left[\left(z+\frac{z^3}{6}+\cdots\right)(1+z^2+z^4+\cdots)\right]
\end{align}

Then $\operatorname{Res}_{z=0}=1+1+\frac{1}{6}=\frac{13}{6}$

But the solutions say that $\operatorname{Res}_{z=0}=\frac{7}{6}$

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Where are you getting $1+1+\frac16$?  I only see $1+\frac16$.

Comment: @RonGordon I made a mistake with the terms

Comment: I changed $sinhz$ to $\sinh z$, coded as \sinh z, and in other ways brought the notation into line with standard usage.  For details, see the edit history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The residue at $z=0$ is the coefficient of the $\frac1z$ term in the expansion
$$
\frac{\sinh(z)}{z^4(1-z^2)}=\frac1{z^4}\left(z+\frac{z^3}6+\frac{z^5}{120}+\dots\right)\left(1+z^2+z^4+\dots\right)
$$
That is the coefficient of $z^3$ term in the expansion
$$
\left(\color{#C00000}{z}+\color{#00A000}{\frac{z^3}6}+\frac{z^5}{120}+\dots\right)\left(\color{#00A000}{1}+\color{#C00000}{z^2}+z^4+\dots\right)
$$
which is
$$
\color{#C00000}{z\cdot z^2}+\color{#00A000}{\frac{z^3}6\cdot1}=\frac76z^3
$$

Comment: Now I realized I was looking at the negative powers like $\frac{1}{z^p}$ but the residue is $\frac{1}{z}$. Thank you.